# Protegè "things has subclass-->"

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I wrote a simple ontology to do some simple test for my project but when i display the graph of the ontology using OntoGraph provided in Protégé GUI i automatically get strange associations:

I get this : (the code is linked at the end of message)

-Thing -- has Sub class --> snomed_title_e

-Thing -- has sub class --> icd_title_e

Why??

ThE OWL file and a snapshot of the graph are [here](http://1drv.ms/ZYjB7w)

Answer (score 0):

`owl:Thing` is the root of all class hierarchies in OWL, that's why it's being shown.
I don't know if there is an option to exclude it from the visualisation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ignazio but the question is why protegè (in Ontograph) makes a direct association between thing and, in this case, only snomed_title_e and icd_title_e. 
If you want the answer can be viewed also as <<Why, for example, "snomed_title_c" isn't directly associated whith "thing"? >>.

It's a bug of ontoGraph? It's a stupid error that i made defining this test file?